# Implementation for configureRoute() of AnnotationClassLoader

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations, symfony-3.2, symfony-cmf

In my Symfony 3.2 app, I create a custom router that extends from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router`.

As required, it implements a `getRouteCollection()` method:

```
public function getRouteCollection() {

    $locator = new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Controller');

    $annotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();
    $classLoader = new AnnotationClassLoader($annotationReader);

    $routeLoader = new Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationDirectoryLoader($locator, $classLoader);
    $routes = $routeLoader->load('.\\', 'annotation');

    return $routes;
}
```

The `AnnotationClassLoader` that is used here is my own, it extends the abstract `Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationClassLoader` class. It implements only one method:

```
protected function configureRoute(Route $route, \ReflectionClass $class, \ReflectionMethod $method, $annot) {

    $route->setDefault('_controller', '???');
    return $route;
}
```

I want to use this to set the default controller for a route that was found in the annotations. The `AnnotationReader` reads all the routes from the source code perfectly fine, but it doesn't set their default controllers at all, which is what I am trying to do in `configureRoute`. That function seems to be called on every route that was found.

**The problem now is to find the appropriate expression to replace `'???'` with.** In the end, I need an outcome such as `'MyPluginBundle:ControllerName:actionName'`. That means I either need to build that string with the information I have (which are the four arguments of the function) or I am taking a totally wrong approach and there is a much easier way to do this.

---

**Example dump of `$route`:**

As you can see, there is no default for `_controller` yet.

```
object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Route)
  private 'path' => string '/my/route' (length=9)
  private 'host' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'schemes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'methods' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'defaults' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'requirements' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'options' => 
    array (size=1)
      'compiler_class' => string 'Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler' (length=39)
  private 'compiled' => null
  private 'condition' => string '' (length=0)
```

**Example dump of `$class`:**

```
object(ReflectionClass)
  public 'name' => string 'MyPluginBundle\Controller\DefaultController' (length=43)
```

**Example dump of `$method`:**

```
object(ReflectionMethod)[174]
  public 'name' => string 'indexAction' (length=11)
  public 'class' => string 'MyPluginBundle\Controller\DefaultController' (length=43)
```

**Example dump of `$annot`:**

```
object(Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route)
  protected 'service' => null
  private 'path' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => string '/my/route' (length=9)
  private 'name' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => string 'name_of_the_route' (length=17)
  private 'requirements' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'options' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'defaults' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'host' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => null
  private 'methods' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'schemes' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'condition' (Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route) => null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the really simple solution (which I found by means of trial and error) is:

```
$route->setDefault('_controller', $method->class.'::'.$method->name);
```

This expression gets you something like:

```
MyPluginBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction
```

Appanrently, the format `MyPluginBundle:Default:index` is just a shortcut and not required.

But this still leaves the question open: **Is there a simpler (e.g. built-in) way to achieve this?**